# How convert seconds to minutes and meter in km?

Tags: java, android

I am trying build to an app, and i need to display travel time in `TextView` , and distance, but this values it show in seconds and meters, i need to convert this, in KM and Minutes, 6000mts in 6.0km and 1453 sec in 24min. I get from String **td** and **ts**, but it pass in mts and seconds

```
 private void parseJSon(String data) throws JSONException {
        if (data == null)
            return;

       List<Route> routes = new ArrayList<Route>();
       JSONObject jsonData = new JSONObject(data);
       JSONArray jsonRoutes = jsonData.getJSONArray("routes");
       long totalDistance = 0;
       int totalSeconds = 0;

       JSONObject jsonDistance = null;
       JSONObject jsonDuration = null;
        for (int i = 0; i < jsonRoutes.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonRoute = jsonRoutes.getJSONObject(i);
            Route route = new Route();

            JSONObject overview_polylineJson = jsonRoute.getJSONObject("overview_polyline");
            JSONArray jsonLegs = jsonRoute.getJSONArray("legs");

            for (int j = 0; j < jsonLegs.length(); j++) {

                jsonDistance = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("distance");
                totalDistance = totalDistance + Long.parseLong(jsonDistance.getString("value"));
                td = String.valueOf(totalDistance);

                /** Getting duration from the json data */
                jsonDuration = ((JSONObject) jsonLegs.get(j)).getJSONObject("duration");
                totalSeconds = totalSeconds + Integer.parseInt(jsonDuration.getString("value"));
                ts = String.valueOf(totalSeconds);


                double dist = totalDistance / 1000.0;
                Log.d("distance", "Calculated distance:" + dist);

                int days = totalSeconds / 86400;
                int hours = (totalSeconds - days * 86400) / 3600;
                int minutes = (totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600) / 60;
                int seconds = totalSeconds - days * 86400 - hours * 3600 - minutes * 60;
                Log.d("duration", days + " days " + hours + " hours " + minutes + " mins" + seconds + " seconds");


            }

            route.distance = td;
            route.duration = ts;

            route.points = decodePolyLine(overview_polylineJson.getString("points"));

            routes.add(route);
        }




       listener.onDirectionFinderSuccess(routes);
    }
```

how can I do it?

Comment: you are converting distance `double dist = totalDistance / 1000.0;` in this line and so do you are converting time in minutes

Comment: So, why in textView show me time in seconds? this 1453

Comment: this code doesn't have the part where you used your `TextView`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
td = String.valueOf(totalDistance * 0.001);
ts = String.valueOf(totalSeconds % 3600) / 60 ;
```

Answer (score 1):

As we know that 
1km=1000 meters and 
1min= 60 seconds
So, if your result is coming in meters and seconds then you could easily convert this into km and minutes by simple mathematics calculation.

Td=total_distance *0.001
Ts= total_duration*60

Answer (score 0):

For time:

```
 long min = TimeUnit.SECONDS.convert(seconds,TimeUnit.MINUTES);
```

For Distance:

```
double km = (double) mtr / 1000;
```

Comment: you solution to convert meters into kilometers always gives 0, because for example if you have 225 meters and you will divide it by 1000 the  result will be converted automatically to integer type, so you expect 0.255km, but .255 will be dropped because of integer. So, to make it works you need to wide mtr to double: double km = (double) mtr /1000;

Answer (score 0):

try this for convert meter to kilometer:

```
public static String convertMeterToKilometer(int totalDistance) {
    double ff = totalDistance / 1000.0;
    BigDecimal bd = BigDecimal.valueOf(ff);
    bd = bd.setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
    return String.valueOf(bd.doubleValue());
}
```